# limits.conf file Changing Max Memory Option

Tags: ram, memory-usage, ulimit

This question might have been asked earlier however i did not find any supported answer. I understand that `ulimit` supports few options from which `max memory size` is one of them. How can i set the same options using `/etc/security/limits.conf` file?

I think setting up `virtual memory` option in `limits.conf` file isn't the same thing as `max memory size`.

Additionally, I know I can edit the user's `.bashrc` file to limit resources using `ulimit`, for example `ulimit -m <mem in Kb>` but that is where user can change these values at any time.

Which one of these in `limits.conf` is equivalent to `ulimit -m`

```
#        - core - limits the core file size (KB)
#        - data - max data size (KB)
#        - fsize - maximum filesize (KB)
#        - memlock - max locked-in-memory address space (KB)
#        - nofile - max number of open files
#        - rss - max resident set size (KB)
#        - stack - max stack size (KB)
#        - cpu - max CPU time (MIN)
#        - nproc - max number of processes
#        - as - address space limit
#        - maxlogins - max number of logins for this user
#        - maxsyslogins - max number of logins on the system
#        - priority - the priority to run user process with
#        - locks - max number of file locks the user can hold
#        - sigpending - max number of pending signals
#        - msgqueue - max memory used by POSIX message queues (bytes)
#        - nice - max nice priority allowed to raise to
#        - rtprio - max realtime priority
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you're talking about bash's `ulimit`. From [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins):

> -m
>   The maximum resident set size (many systems do not honor this limit).

Of the entries in your question, `rss` is also max resident set size.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I am looking for equivalent to `ulimit -m`  in `limits.conf` file. User can change `ulimit -m` at any given time if it is set in their shell and i don't want to set it up system wide for all users.

Comment: @rulebreaker4 isn't that what I said? `rss` is the equivalent. I linked to the bash manual to make it clear what `-m` is  (you said it's "max memory size", it's actually max "resident set size").

Comment: I have `ulimit -m` say "unlimited" whereas in /etc/security/limits.conf it has a value of `10000`. How awkward as systems today have > 10GB of RAM.